# (How) can CSV data be transposed for display in tabular

Tags: tables, csvsimple

I can use the csvsimple package to automatically display data from a CSV file in a tabular environment. Can the same be achieved in transposed (rows to columns and vice versa) form , as shown by the second hand-coded example?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{transpose.csv}
course,J,Js,F,Fs,G,Gs,T,Ts
1,4,4,4,4,3,3,5,5
2,3,7,2,6,2,5,4,9
3,4,11,3,9,5,10,2,11
4,2,13,7,16,3,13,7,18
5,7,20,3,19,7,20,7,25
6,5,25,3,23,7,27,2,27
7,3,28,5,28,2,29,3,30
8,6,34,4,32,7,36,3,33
9,4,38,2,34,3,39,7,40
10,4,42,2,36,6,45,2,42
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{rcccc}
  \toprule
  \# & Subj J & Subj F & Subj G & Subj T \\
  \midrule
    \csvreader[head to column names,late after line=\\]{transpose.csv}{}%
    {\course & \J & \F & \G & \T}
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace{2em}

\begin{tabular}{lcccccccccc}
  \toprule
  \# & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
  \midrule
  Subj J & 4 & . & . & . & & &  &  &  & 4 \\
  Subj F & 4 & . & . &  & & &  &  & . & 2 \\
  Subj G & 3 & . &  &  & & &  & . & . & 6 \\
  Subj T & 5 &  &  &  & & & . & . & . & 2 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Graphically: top shows the current behaviour, bottom the desired output:

[image: Top table from CSV file, desired bottom table with transposed rows/columns]

Comment: I did not know that `csvsimple` exists. Seems to be useful. As there is no option to `scvreader` to transpose you seem have to do it yourself. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/K8UTcsocIJ0 for an awk script. If you only have a small amount of csv-data you can use MS Excel (at least the current version): Copy your data, right click (at some table sheet with enough room) and choose "transpose" from the context menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought was to use [`pgfplotstable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable). You can choose which columns (of the original table) to plot by the `columns` key in the `\pgfplotstabletranspose` macro. The `colnames from` key says that I want the columns of the transposed table to be named based on the values in the `course` column of the original table. The `postproc cell content` line adds `Subj` before each of the course subjects.

```
begin{filecontents*}{transpose.csv}
course,J,Js,F,Fs,G,Gs,T,Ts
1,4,4,4,4,3,3,5,5
2,3,7,2,6,2,5,4,9
3,4,11,3,9,5,10,2,11
4,2,13,7,16,3,13,7,18
5,7,20,3,19,7,20,7,25
6,5,25,3,23,7,27,2,27
7,3,28,5,28,2,29,3,30
8,6,34,4,32,7,36,3,33
9,4,38,2,34,3,39,7,40
10,4,42,2,36,6,45,2,42
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[
    col sep=comma,
]{transpose.csv}\normal

\pgfplotstabletranspose[
    colnames from=course,
    columns={course,J,F,G,T},
]\transpose\normal

\begin{center}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    string type,
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    every col no 0/.style={
        column type={l},
        column name={\#},
        postproc cell content/.append style={/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={Subj }{}},
    },
]\transpose
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplotstabletranspose]

Answer (score 3):

My idea is to build up the transposed rows step by step with every data line. Afterwards, the table is generated:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{transpose.csv}
course,J,Js,F,Fs,G,Gs,T,Ts
1,4,4,4,4,3,3,5,5
2,3,7,2,6,2,5,4,9
3,4,11,3,9,5,10,2,11
4,2,13,7,16,3,13,7,18
5,7,20,3,19,7,20,7,25
6,5,25,3,23,7,27,2,27
7,3,28,5,28,2,29,3,30
8,6,34,4,32,7,36,3,33
9,4,38,2,34,3,39,7,40
10,4,42,2,36,6,45,2,42
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,etoolbox}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{rcccc}
  \toprule
  \# & Subj J & Subj F & Subj G & Subj T \\
  \midrule
    \csvreader[head to column names,late after line=\\]{transpose.csv}{}%
    {\course & \J & \F & \G & \T}
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace{2em}

% These macros save the data
\def\columnAll{}
\def\courseAll{}
\def\JAll{}
\def\FAll{}
\def\GAll{}
\def\TAll{}

% Reading data and store into the auxiliary macros
\csvreader[head to column names]{transpose.csv}{}%
  {\edef\columnAll{\columnAll c}
   \edef\courseAll{\courseAll&\course}%
   \edef\JAll{\JAll&\J}%
   \edef\FAll{\FAll&\F}%
   \edef\GAll{\GAll&\G}%
   \edef\TAll{\TAll&\T}}%

% Finally: output as table
\begin{tabular}{l\columnAll}
  \toprule
  \# \courseAll\\
  \midrule
  Subj J \JAll\\
  Subj F \FAll\\
  Subj G \GAll\\
  Subj T \TAll\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really like the simplicity of your answer, but I think that the `pgfplotstable` is the 'sharper knife' for the job.